# time complexity for the following

Tags: time, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

```
int i=1,s=1;
while(s<=n)
{
i++;
s=s+i;
}
```

time complexity for this is O(root(n)).
I do not understood it how.
since the series is going like 1+2+...+k . 
please help.

Answer (score 3):

Let the loop execute `x` times. Now, the loop will execute as long as `s` is less than `n`.

We have :

After 1st iteration :
`s = s + 1`
After 2nd iteration :
`s = s + 1 + 2`

As it goes on for x iterations, Finally we will have

`1 + 2 ... + x <= n`

=> `(x * (x + 1)) / 2 <= n`

=>   `O(x^2)` <= n

=>   `x= O (root(n))`

Answer (score 3):

`s(k) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... k = (k + 1) * k / 2`

for `s(k) >= n` you need at least k steps. `n = (k + 1) * k / 2`, thus `k = -1/2 +- sqrt(1 + 4 * n)/2`;

you ignore constants and coeficients and `O(-1/2 + sqrt(1+4n)/2) = O(sqrt(n))`

Answer (score 0):

This computes the sum `s(k)=1+2+...+k` and stops when `s(k) > n`.

Since `s(k)=k*(k+1)/2`, the number of iterations required for `s(k)` to exceed `n` is `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: how did you figure out the O(sqrt(n)) part? Do we need to solve it ? or in problems if i find "s(k)=k*(k+1)/2" this,  can i directly assume it to be O(sqrt(n)?